# How to set Sikuli path

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I'm using SikuliX to test my game. Here's the code I'm running:

```
public void testApplication() throws FindFailed {

    // pass if there are merely no warnings/exceptions
    /* Example of using Jelly Tools (additional test dependencies required) with gui(true):
        new ActionNoBlock("Help|About", null).performMenu();
        new NbDialogOperator("About").closeByButton();
     */


    try {
        plugin.start(gameData, world);
        screen.wait("/Resources/playerStart.png");
    } catch (FindFailed ex) {

        System.out.println("PlayerStart failed!");
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(1, world.size());
    try {
        screen.wait("playerMoveForward.png");
        screen.type("wwwwwwww");
    } catch (FindFailed ex) {
        System.out.println("Player movement failed!");
    }

    try {
        screen.wait("playerTurnRight.png");
        screen.type("dddddddd");
    } catch (FindFailed ex) {
        System.out.println("Player turn failed!");
    }

}
```

I'm getting a null pointer on first `screen.wait()`, so the path is not right, and I have no idea how to get the right one. The full path of the image I'm trying to use is:

```
C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AsteroidTEST\AsteroidsTEST\application\src\test\java\Resources\playerStart.png
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Might be, but that link doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your Sikuli path using `ImagePath.setBundlePath` static method like this:

```
ImagePath.setBundlePath("C:/temp/sikulipatterns/"); //insert your own path instead
```